# transform pair of key value tags to <key>value</key> in Oracle integration Cloud

Tags: xml, oracle, integration, xslt-2.0, soa

i have xml payload that is sent to Oracle integration cloud with the following format

```
<keyName>key1</keyName>
<keyValue>value1</keyValue>
<keyName>key2</keyName>
<keyValue>value2</keyValue>
.
.
```

i want to transform it to this format with xsl expression

to the following :

```
<key1>value1</key1>
<key2>value2</key2>
<key3>value3</key3>
```

how to achieve that ?

Answer (score 0):

You can handle this by using `following-sibling`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" exclude-result-prefixes="#all" version="2.0">

    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="root">
        <root>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
        </root>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="keyName">
        <xsl:element name="{.}">
            <xsl:value-of select="following-sibling::node()[self::keyValue][1]"/>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="keyValue"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Link: https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/6rexjik